# How do I install the Flash plugin for Firefox on Ubuntu offline?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, flash, plugins

I've got a `libflashplayer.so` that I've downloaded beforehand, but I have no idea what to do with it.

How do I install the Flash plug-in for Firefox on Ubuntu offline?

Comment: which "deb" did you download?  specific filename please.

Comment: I downloaded and installed install_flash_player_10_linux.deb (from http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/install_flash_player_10_linux.deb).

Comment: this ubuntu is such a piece of junk...

Comment: its not junk. The setup through libflashplayer.so is the easiest. Follow what i told in answer.

Comment: If you think Ubuntu is junk then why are you using it?

Comment: none of your biz, pal.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is downloading the **libflashplayer.so** file from [official site](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer).

Extract the **install_flash_player_10_linux.tar.gz** file.

> Make a new directory named **plugins**
>   in **/home/username/.mozilla**
>   directory.
>
> Copy the **libflashplayer.so** file to the
>   **"plugins"** directory.
>
> Restart the browser.

There you go. You now have flash installed without any using any package manager or any compilation.

Comment: +1: That's how I did it after trying to install it through the package manager (I had random problems with that) and it worked like a charm.

Comment: That fraking so is there (and everywhere) but flash doesn't work!!!

Comment: as per community standards, you should accept the answer if it worked.. Thats how the superuser works.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on this for hours and finally got it to work...

Beg borrow or steal your way to the legendary `libflashplayer.so` (note that this is NOT the flash installer; check out your error messages to see what it is trying to download and go get it manually)

Sudo copy the file to `/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/ubufox@ubuntu.com/plugins` (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin`

**Edit:** You need to enable the partner repository for this package (`archive.canonical.com`)

**Edit 2:** Oh, 8.04...well, there is a package [avalaible in the multiverse repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/hardy/web/flashplugin-nonfree) which will install the flash plugin. For how to enable multiverse, please [read this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

Comment: a) he's updated to ask for an offline install, b) that package name doesn't exist in ubuntu 9.10. (is it a 9.04 or earlier package?  a nonstandard repository?)

Comment: ubuntu 8.04. I got deb and installed it but nothing...

Comment: @~quack: What? Ohhhh...this is coming from the partner repository...sorry, didn't check that back, edited my answer.

Comment: @Bobby ahh, that makes sense.  haven't enabled that on my ubuntu system.  thanks for the additional detail.

Comment: I need to enable the partner repository? How to do that?

Comment: @Bobby: I think the OP's Ubuntu machine isn't connected to the internet...

Comment: @musicfreak: true, but if we correctly identify the package and where it comes from, a web link can be used to d/l the package file on another internet-enabled system and transfer via sneakernet.

Comment: @musicfreak, @~quack: Of course! packages.ubuntu.com is holding the repos as well, thanks for the input!