# Installing Flash while running Ubuntu from a USB Drive?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, flash

I am running Ubuntu from a USB drive (Hard drive is messed up and cannot install waiting on replacement parts etc) and I need to have Adobe Flash Installed yet I cannot figure out how to do it. When I tried to install via Ubuntu Software Centere I get an error that says:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

his error could be caused by required additional software packages which are 
missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between 
software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Details:
flashplugin-installer: Depends: ia32-libs (>= 2.2ubuntu18) but it is not 
going to be installed
```

I have read this post: [How do I install the Flash plugin for Firefox on Ubuntu offline?](https://superuser.com/questions/113489/how-do-I-install-flash-plugin-for-Firefox-on-Ubuntu-offline) and tried to do it manually but I cannot find the Mozilla Folder.

Can I install flash while running Ubuntu from a USB? How?

***EDIT*** I found the Mozilla Plugin folder (path = `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugin`) but when I attempt to transfer the .so file there I get permission denied. Any ideas around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I finally came across a solution that actualy worked.

The solution was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50763/i-cant-download-adobe-flash) and was from another stackexchange site (askubuntu).

[Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) was the solution.

Hope others can use this in the future that come across this issue.

Also if you are having issues with Flash in Ubuntu try Flash-Aid, highly recommended. =>

Answer (score 0):

You can also place the .so file in ~/.mozilla/plugins if you don't have admin privileges.  Also, you appear to be on 32-bit linux.  I'd recommend downloading the preview release [here](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer11.html), which works on 64-bit.

Comment: That did not work, only Flash Aid would